# Calculating whether there will be something in a grid position based upon the number of grid items

Tags: math, grid

Consider I have 26 images which are split up into a 7 row, 4 column grid. Obviously not every grid spot will have an image in it, since there are more grid spots than images. But how do I figure out whether or not a grid spot has anything in it, using only mathematics?

Example:

[image: Example grid]

How would I know if there is anything in the spot where the yellow rectangle is (row 7, column 3)?

Answer (score 0):

I assum that you fill the grid in order,  then you can assing a number to every cell as  #row * number of columns + #column  (if you are filling by rows as in the image, and there will be image if cell number <= number of images